# HTTP status code in an https domain

Tags: https, http-status-code

I am reading about the error 504 Gateaway Time-out error. All the websites I have found, relate the 504 error to HTTP status code. the error is displayed if visiting a https website. According to what I learned in a computer security curse https is more secure than http. However I have only found HTTP status codes. Why I cannot find the https ones?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding status codes, HTTPS is no different to HTTP: the *protocol* itself (and thus the attached status codes, error codes, syntax, handling, …) remains untouched.

HTTPS is simply HTTP where the protocol is encrypted (either via TLS or—previously—via SSL), so there is no change in the *content*.

Answer (score 3):

Because they are exactly the same.

HTTPS is HTTP with added encryption, but the actual application protocol doesn't change; the requests and responses between clients and servers use the same syntax and status codes.

You can think of it as speaking English on a secure phone line vs. an insecure one; regardless of the line security, you'll still be speaking English.